# How to Embed a Template Variable Inside a Hyperlink - Django Template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am brand new to web development, Django, python, html, etc. I have a basic Django app that displays a list of publication titles that have been entered into the database. This works fine.

I now want to make it so that each publication title is a link that - when clicked on - renders another template with the details of the publication that was clicked. So far, I know how to get the publication link to render a template, but I am trying to figure out how to pass in the publication title to the hyperlink so that the data that is rendered in the details template will be specific to the title that was chosen.

Here is what I have in my publication template which displays all the publications (it is incorrect, but hopefully it clarifies what I am trying to do):

```
<html>
    <head><title>Publications</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Publications</h1>
        <ul>
            {% for publication in publication_list %}
            <li><strong><a href="/publications/{{publication.title}}/detail">{{ publication.title}}</strong></li></a>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

For the sake of context, the url pattern that handles this is:

```
url(r'^(?P<detail_type>\w+)/(?P<link_item>\w+)/detail$', get_details)
```

And the view function is:
    // note: I may have some of the logic/syntax wrong here, but this is the basic idea

```
def get_details(request, detail_type=None, link_item=None):
    if detail_type == "publications":
        publication = Publication.objects.filter(title__iexact=link_item)
        return render(request, 'publication_detail.html', {'detail_type' : detail_type, 'publication' : publication})
    elif ....
```

Like I said, I am very much a beginner so if I am approaching this in wrong way, any suggestions or resources are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) you can easily do this with the `url` template tag.

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<detail_type>\w+)/(?P<link_item>\w+)/detail$', get_details, name='details')
```

#### template

```
{% url 'details' 'publications' publication.title %}
```

I hope you know about [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) too, it is much better for urls than a normal `CharField`.

---

An alternative:

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<detail_type>\w+)/(?P<pk>\w+)/detail$', get_details, name='details')
```

#### template

```
{% url 'details' 'publications' publication.pk %}
```

#### views.py

```
def get_details(request, detail_type=None, pk=None):
    if detail_type == "publications":
        publication = Publication.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'publication_detail.html', {'detail_type' : detail_type, 'publication' : publication})
    elif ....
```

This uses the primary key of the entry instead of the title. If you want to have a url with the title in it you will want to add and use a [`SlugField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) on your model.

Comment: Thanks, Just tried this and got the following error: NoReverseMatch at /publications
Reverse for 'details' with arguments '(u'publications', u'Awesome TV Shows')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: Thanks again. Ok, I see what you are saying and I will investigate SlugField. One question though - I used the alternative code you posted and the publications are not displaying as links (they are not click-able). I implemented the URL tag in the template like:   <ul>{% for publication in publication_list %}
<li><strong>{% url 'details' 'publications' publication.pk %}</strong></li>{% endfor %}</ul>
                                                      is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, had to go and I should have included the whole template since just the tag may not have been clear about its usage. Glad you figured it out though

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty good to me, although you may want to use `get` as opposed to `filter` in your view function if all the publication titles are unique and you want to pass an instance of `Publication` rather than a queryset (containing one item) into the detail template.  This would throw an error of there were 0 or >1 matches, but it sounds like that's probably the behavior you'd want

However, I'm not sure what it is that you're missing here.  What does `publication_detail.html` look like?  You should have essentially everything you need in the above code to render the details, assuming they're all contained in the relevant Publication instance.

Comment: the problem is this line: "<a href="/publications/(?P<{{publication.title}}>\w+)/detail">{{ publication.title}}</strong></li>
    </a>"  I think that having {{publication.title}} inside the hyperlink does not seem to work.  I get a "page not found" error so the publication_detail.html is not getting rendered.

Comment: i see, thanks.  as the answer below indicates, using the `url` tag to specify your `href` will resolve that for you quite easily.